# By Default Values of Query Execution in SSMS

Tags: ssms

[image: ***SSMS Tool > Options > Query Execution***]

Where can I check and update the settings of General SQL Server Query Execution Setting in SSMS.

I need to push the settings on all the clients for `SET ROWCOUNT` and Execution-Time Out, but not able to locate the file or registry settings for the same

Connect SSMS --> Tools --> Options --> Query Execution --> SQL Server --> General

Version used is SQL Server Management Studio 2012 and later

Comment: If anyone can help